# In jMeter how to make a variable dynamic, as one month can be process only once

Tags: selenium, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

In jMeter how to make a variable dynamic, as one month can be process only once

To make my problem clear I would like to explain the background of the system. There is a Payroll application in which I need to check the salary processing time and if multiple users process salary on the system. But condition is if a user process 1 month's salary (say January month's salary).

But if I need to load test this scenario with multiple thread and ramp-up time then I have to repeat this (means same month's salary need to process multiple time) that is not possible. Can you please give me an idea how to handle this situation.

But there is an option to change year then month then I can select new month but there are limited month in a year, there is year drop-down also but. If I process month's salary and change month by changing year then month, here I need thousands of years and months that I not possible in the application.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have limited Year/Month combinations and each combination can be processed only once - it doesn't make sense to load test it.

Comment: No, actually there is a "salary pressing for a month" functionality that need to load test. But the condition is one month salary can be processed only once. So I can not simulate multiple threads for same month salary processing to load test as in second time it will display error that salary already processed.
If I the month check can be by passed then it can be done, but it is not possible to by pass this check. That's why I am asking if there is another way to get this done.